# Scala Type Mismatch issue when using import from different scope

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, type-mismatch

In my project(play 2.4 with slick 3.0), I have a setup: using MySQL for production and H2 for unit testing(start to feel that it is a horrible idea). To do that, I have to import `slick.driver.JdbcProfile` instead of any specific driver (e.g. `slick.driver.MySQLDriver`) and import its `api._` in my DAO class, like this:

```
class SomeDAO(val context: MyContext){
  import context.profile.api._
  import context.SOME_TYPE

  def invoke(para: SOME_TYPE) = { ... }

  // other DBIO...

}
```

Everything is OK so far, however, I have a service class that requires this DAO, and a type in context as a parameter:

```
class MyService(val context: MyContext){

   val someDAO = new SomeDAO(context)
   import someDAO.context.SOME_TYPE  // it works
   // import context.SOME_TYPE   // Type mismatch! But how to avoid it???

   def invokeDAOMethod(para: SOME_TYPE) = someDAO.invoke(para) // where mismatch occurred
   // expect: MyService.this.someDao.context.SOME_TYPE
   // actual: MyService.this.context.SOME_TYPE

}
```

Problem heppens when I try to import a type from exact the same `context` instance, intuitively speaking, I'm using the "**Same**" type here, right?

Can someone explain this kind of behaviour and give hint about patterns to cut this kind of 'non-sense' I wrote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using path-dependent types. They are literally dependent on paths, not on its content.

Consider that example:

```
class Store {
  case class Box[T](box : T)
  def box[T](b : T) = Box[T](b)
  def unbox[T](b : Box[T]) : T = b.box
}

object Assign {
  val x = new Store()
  val y = x
  val box = x.box[Int](2)
  val ub = y.unbox[Int](box)
}
```

You may assume naively that `x` and `y` are practically identical, they share the same content and the same type. True for the content. Wrong for types. And compiler nicely provide you with a type error:

> error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : dependent.Assign.x.Box[Int]
>
> required: dependent.Assign.y.Box[Int]

But you could tell the compiler that `x` and `y` should share the same path-dependent types despite being different literal paths

```
object Assign {
  val x = new Store()
  val y : x.type = x
  val box = x.box[Int](2)
  val ub = y.unbox[Int](box)
}
```

With `val y : x.type = x` the compiler would success.

Your issue has the similar nature, and the solution is similar too: you should specify type equivalence explicitly. Change the SameDAO definition to accept type parameter

```
class SomeDAO[MC <: MyContext](val context: MC){
  ...
}
```

and pass appropriate type upon creation:

```
class MyService(val context: MyContext){
  val someDAO = new SomeDAO[context.type](context)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the pain by moving the type definition to a `object`, therefore the type is imported statically.

Still not sure how to inherit types and how to introduce some dynamic components into this `object`

**UPDATE:** it is actually called "Path Dependent Types" in Scala.